# understanding kernel boot shell

Tags: shell, kernel, boot

From my understanding:
The first process being execute is the init (with other modern names) process with pid 1.
Later on according to the /etc/inittab and all the /rdc. folders' scripts rest of the programs are being execute upon .

1.The shell (bash shell in my case with login prompt) process starts running only after all the processes I mentioned above. So if my shell didn't opened yet how exactly all those scripts are being executed?   to run a script we need a shell that will run it. right?

2. where I can find the script that says at which point exactly my bash shell start running?
3. before my bash shell is running , can I send signals (Ctrl z/x/c) to one of the processes who start running upon startup?
4. I have a process with "scanf" in it. When I press the keyboard the process receives my input.
   Considering that process started running at startup like I mentioned above before my shell did. How it received my input? my shell opens only after this process finishes.

Comment: This is would be more on topic for [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). I think you're really overestimating the role and importance of your interactive login shell. 1. It's not involved in running scripts (they're run by non-interactive shell instances, whether at boot time or not), 2. it's not started on boot (only on login), 3. It's not involved with those signals (that's the terminal), 4. It's not involved in program input (the program reads straight from the terminal)

Answer (score 0):

1. The shell program can run non-interactively as a script interpreter, in that case it can run before you login.
2. The shell process is started by the login program after you typed your username and password.
3. Signals are passed via the *controlling terminal* of the process, as long as the program has a controlling terminal, it would be able to receive signals from its controlling terminal.
4. `scanf()` read from the standard input of the process, which is also linked to its controlling terminal. So ditto.

Comment: So if I understood correctly:     1. The scripts at boot time are run by a shell instance which I can't see/interact with..     2. The shell process (the one that I can interact with) started by the login process which started by the init process       3. the terminal is the one responsible for sending signals and not the shell?  @that other guy